# Oracle Forms - EXECUTE_QUERY not working

Tags: oracle11g, oracleforms

I am trying to create a button which does exactly the same work of 'execute query' button in the smart bar.

Below are the steps I tried, but isnt working. Please tell me what am I doing wrong.
I am creating a simple form using Oracle XE Express Edition 11g and Oracle Forms 10g.

This is a very simple form that displays employee details (Form).
I created a button 'Display', which when pressed, calls `execute_query;`

When I clicked display button, it gives:

> FRM:40202 : Field must be entered.

Additionally the cursor is blinking in the Employee ID field.  The 'Execute Query' button in the 'Smart Bar' works fine.

Could you please show me how to make it work?

Comment: Please read [ask] to help people answer your question. Specifically **try "providing the code"**.

Comment: there is no specific code actually... I created a button --> Trigger (When_button_pressed) --> PL/SQL editor --> execute_query;
should we add any more code ? actually i am not sure ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys... Got the fix from a different forum.

**`Go to the property palette of the field where the cursor is (In my case it is Employee ID) --> Under 'Data' --> 'Required' --> set to 'NO'`**

The above method will work but a better approach is

in PLSQL Editor (button - When_button_pressed) - enter the below code

```
GO_BLOCK(NO_VALIDATE);
EXECUTE_QUERY;
```

Then in property palette --> Mouse Navigatable --> set to 'NO'

Save and run the form... You are good to GO.

Comment: This is not correct, Now you made a field that is required not mandatory anymore.
You should probably look at what other trigger you made. The record has no longer the status NEW. And because of that your trigger with execute_query will validate the record before executing the query.

Comment: Yes... You are right 
Please see the modified approach.

Answer (score 0):

write a query EXECUTE_QUERY(NO_VALIDATE);
then it will not show an error FRM:40202 : Field must be entered.